# GNU Parallel echo job number

Tags: gnu, gnu-parallel

So I have this code: `parallel --jobs 5 curl --write-out '\\n  %{http_code}\\n' --silent --head --output /dev/null https://example.com/id={} ::: {427240690783..427240690793}`

Which returns 10 lots of 404's.

If the HTTP Response code was 200, I want to echo out the current job iteration ID, displayed within the {}. How would I go about echoing these?

Apologies, I'm brand new to GNU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a command gets this complex I would normally make function:

```
doit() {
  curl --write-out '\n  %{http_code}\n' --silent --head --output /dev/null https://example.com/id="$1"
}
export -f 
parallel doit ::: {427240690783..427240690793}
```

This is because it is easy to test if the function does the right thing for one input. When it does that, you call GNU Parallel to call the function.

Here you probably want something like:

```
grep200() {
  status=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --head --output /dev/null "$1"); 
  if [ $status == 200 ] ; then
    echo "$1";
  fi;
}
export -f grep200
parallel grep200 https://example.com/id={} ::: {427240690783..427240690793}
```

Comment: Thanks Ole! 

That's exactly what I ended up doing in the end. Many thanks!